Formula for a matrix's characteristic polynomial as the exponential of a series in $\mathrm{tr}(A^k)$
I want to prove the following equation
$$ \det(x - A) = x^n \exp \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k x^k} \mathrm{tr} (A^k) $$
where $A \in \mathbb C ^{n \times n}$. In the case where $A$ is a scalar, this can be shown by taking the exponential of the Taylor expansion
$$ \log(x-A) = \log(x) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k x^k} A^k, $$
using $\frac{d^k}{dx^k} \log(x) = (-1)^{k-1} (k-1)! x^{-k}$.
How would one do this for matrices in higher dimensions?
Edit: I have to amend the formula as given above. It really holds for $\det(x+A)$. For $\det(x-A)$, the series should not be alternating:
$$ \det(x - A) = x^n \exp \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{-1}{k x^k} \mathrm{tr} (A^k). $$

reduce $A$ to an upper triangular matrix

Good idea, thanks.

One has :
$$
\begin{align}
\det(x-A) 
   &= x^n\det\left(1-\frac{A}{x}\right) & (1) \\
   &= x^n\exp\left(\operatorname{tr}\ln\left(1-\frac{A}{x}\right)\right) & (2) \\
   &= x^n\exp\left(\operatorname{tr}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\left(\frac{A}{x}\right)^k\right)\right) & (3) \\
   &= x^n\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\frac{\operatorname{tr}A^k}{x^k}\right) & (4)
\end{align}
$$
where we used :

$(1)$ the multilinearity of the determinant ;
$(2)$ the famous identity $\det e^X = e^{\operatorname{tr}X}$ ;
$(3)$ the Taylor expansion of the logarithm ;
$(4)$ the linearity of the trace.


Very nice, thank you!

@notmyrealname  You're welcome ;)
